# Matching strings from an API for Search Suggestions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I am currently working on recreating this functionality: [Desired Functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBZOp.png)

The current state of my code is here:
app/assets/javascript/schools.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   console.log( 'Jquery is working' );

$('#user_zip').keyup(function( event ) {
console.log ( 'Keyup is working' );
var zip_user_entry = $(event.target).val()

// ajax request
console.log(zip_user_entry);
$.get('/schools_in_zip_code', {zip_code: zip_user_entry})
});
});
```

My Schools Controller app/controllers/schools_controller.rb

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @schools = School.all.limit(15)
    respond_to do |format|
       format.json { render json: @schools }
    end
 end

 def in_zip_code
   @schools = School.all
   @school_suggestions = School.where(zip_code: LIKE params[:zip_code])
      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @school_suggestions }
      end
 end

 end
```

Here is what my views look like: file - app/views/schools/in_zip_code.html.erb

```
Actual view partial code for building a select box with all the school options goes here. You will have access to the @schools variable. (still working on this)
```

app/views/schools/in_zip_code.js

```
$('#selector-for-schools-in-this-zip-code').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "in_zip_code"))%>');
```

Last but not least here is my config/routes.rb

```
get 'schools_in_zip_code' => 'schools#in_zip_code'
resources :schools, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

The thing that I am struggling most with is that I am not getting my json of school_suggestions from my schools controller. My index action of schools is giving me json but not school_suggestion. Whenever I have the KeyUp event get fired this is the current error that I get:

```
SyntaxError (/Users/philipengles/2016/january/ac_commonlit/commonlit/app/controllers/schools_controller.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...ool.where(zip_code: LIKE params[:zip_code])
```

Sorry for such a long post but I wanted to give you the full picture of my current status. If anyone has any suggestions or any blog posts that relate to this material that would be super helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error in your ActiveRecord query:

```
@school_suggestions = School.where(zip_code: LIKE params[:zip_code])
```

The ActiveRecord API doesn't provide a way to build LIKE queries, so you need to use a string condition with a wildcard:

```
@school_suggestions = School.where("zip_code LIKE ?", params[:zip_code])
```

Also [read this part of the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, that indeed was one part of the puzzle.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion on how to see @school_suggestions please let me know